# Output of Removing 3s does not come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array on numbers as input, remove all elements from the array which are either multiple of 3 or have the digit 3 in them. For e.g. 13 and 15 will be both removed from the array if they are present.

**MyApproach**

To remove 3, I have made function removeMultiple which first remove  Multiple of 3 if it exist.And then I also made function removeDigit Which removes the digit 3 int it if the number is not multiple of 3.
But I am not getting expected output.

> MyQuestion:What I am doing wrong in my code.Can anyone guide me?

@Edit:

```
boolean containsDigit3(int[] arr,int index)
{

  boolean b1=false;
  while(arr[index]>0)
  {
        int p=arr[index]%10;
         if(p==3)
         {

            b1=true;

         }
         arr[index]=arr[index]/10;  
  }

     if(b1==true)
     return true;
     else
     return false;
 }

boolean isMultipleOf3(int[] arr,int index)
{
  boolean b1=false;

        int p=arr[index]%3;
         if(p==0)
         {

            b1=true;

         }



     if(b1==true)
     return true;
     else 
     return false;



}

 public int[] remove(int[] arr) 

 {
    // Array of max length
    int p[] = new int[arr.length];
    int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  {
    if (!isMultipleOf3(arr,i) && !containsDigit3(arr,i))
    {
        p[i] = arr[i];
        ++count;
    }
  }
    // Array of right length - System.arraycopy not allowed?!
   int[] q = new int[count];
   for (int i = 0; i < q.length; ++i) 
   {
     q[i] = p[i];
   }
  return q;
}

Parameters                   Actual Output       Expected Output

'{24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42}' {0}                  {40}
```

Comment: What are you allowed to use? List<Integer> might be a smart idea (iterate array, put into list if not a '3#)

Comment: This code doesn't compile - there is no return statement in `removeDigit3`.

Comment: @Jan I have to hard code it.No inbuilt functions allowed.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am unable to write code there how to insert element into array when the element does not contain 3 in its digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating on full arrays might be more difficult than it has to be. Break down your code into small and accurate parts, don't mix up iterating and copying an array with checking-for-3-logic.

Consider this method to remove those unwanted elements:

```
public int[] remove(int[] arr) {
    // Array of max length
    int p[] = new int[arr.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!isMultipleOf3(arr[i]) && !containsDigit3(arr[i])) {
            p[count] = arr[i];
            ++count;
        }
    }
    // Array of right length - System.arraycopy not allowed?!
    int[] q = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length; ++i) {
        q[i] = p[i];
    }
    return q;
}
```

Now you can focus on very, very simple methods for `boolean isMultipleOf3(int i)` and `boolean containsDigit3(int i)`

Here's some very basic implementations:

```
private boolean containsDigit3(int i) {
    //indexOf returns position of character '3' in String that
    //represents the number i. If '3' is not found it returns -1
    //so indexOf('3') >= 0 is another way of saying "contains digit 3"
    return Integer.toString(i).indexOf('3') >= 0;
}

private boolean isMultipleOf3(int i) {
    return i%3 == 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting correct output again.I edited the code according to your instructions.But only some minor changes.Can you have a look please.

Comment: Yes,My Apology to you sir.But When I edited the code,I still faced some issues due to which I thought the best Answers would get.

Comment: it has to be p[count] = arr[i]; instead of p[i] = arr[i] in loop - that fixes it.

Comment: @Yes Thank you.I will not repeat that again

Comment: Sir return Integer.toString(i).indexOf('3') >= 0;Can you explain your condition a bit with example.

Comment: Integer.toString(i) will return a string at that index.Lets, say 31 .Now It will search for index of 3.I haven't understood >=0?Why you have put this condition

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this

```
public int[] remove(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr)
                    .filter(i -> i % 3 != 0)
                    .filter(i -> !(""+i).contains("3"))
                    .toArray();
}
```

> I have to hard code it.No inbuilt functions allowed.

In that case I would do something like the above except "hard coded"

```
public static int[] remove(int[] arr) {
    int[] ret = new int[arr.length];
    int count = 0;
    OUTER:
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            continue;
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0) {
            if (j % 10 == 3)
                continue OUTER;
            j /= 10;
        }
        ret[count++] = i;
    }
    // do the same as Arrays.copyOf(ret, count)
    if (ret.length > count) {
        int[] ret2 = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            ret2[i] = ret[i];
        return ret2;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

so

```
int[] arr = {24, 27, 30, 31, 34, 37, 40, 42};
int[] arr2 = remove(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

prints

```
[40]
```

Comment: @Jasonarora I would do the same thing except without using any built in functions.